# Two way binding with URL get params and Form value (options and sliderbar)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently, I can fetch the GET params via `$location.$$search`.

However, I still have no idea how to do 2 way binding for the URL and FORM on the following case.

As the following demo picture, when user updates the FORM elements the corresponding URL should be: `https://lazyair.co/en/user/quick_search/index#?from=TOKYO&to=TAIPEI&depart=2016/06/03~2016/06/06&return=2016/06/08~2016/06/11&chart_type=column&depart_slider=10:00~24:00`

[image: inline]

Demo page: https://lazyair.co/en/user/quick_search/index

## Sliderbar directive JavaScript code

```
  'use strict';

  quick_search_app.directive('ionslider',function($timeout){

      var get_hour_minute, getHHMMformat, isDepartureAtInInterval;

      get_hour_minute = function(value) {
        var hours, minutes;
        hours = Math.floor(value / 60);
        minutes = value - (hours * 60);
        if (hours.length === 1) {
          hours = '0' + hours;
        }
        if (minutes.length === 1) {
          minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }
        return [hours, minutes];
      };

      getHHMMformat = function(values) {
        var hours, minutes;

              hours = values[0].toString();
              minutes = values[1].toString();
              if (hours.length === 1) {
                hours = '0' + hours;
              }
              if (minutes.length === 1) {
                minutes = '0' + minutes;
              }
              return hours + ':' + minutes;
            }
      isDepartureAtInInterval = function(departure_at, slider){
          var t = new Date(Date.parse(departure_at))
          var HHMM_in_minutes = t.getUTCHours()*60 + t.getMinutes();
          return slider.from <= HHMM_in_minutes && slider.to >= HHMM_in_minutes;
      }
      var updateFlighSeries = function(slider, flight_series) {
        $.each(flight_series, function() {
            var current_series = this;
            angular.forEach(current_series.data, function(value, key) {
                  if(isDepartureAtInInterval(value.departure_at, slider)){
                      this.visible = true ;
                  }else{
                      this.visible = false ;
                  }
              }, current_series);
        });
      }
      return{
          restrict:'AE',
          scope: false,
          controller: 'quick_search_ctrl',

          link:function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
              $(element).ionRangeSlider({
                      hide_min_max: true,
                      keyboard: true,
                      min: 0,
                      max: 1440,
                      from: 0,
                      to: 1440,
                      type: 'double',
                      step: 30,
                      prefix: "",
                      chartConfig: element.attr("chart-config"),
                      grid: true,
                      prettify: function (value) {
                        return getHHMMformat(get_hour_minute(value));
                      },
                      onChange: function(slider) {
                          var _this = this;
                          updateFlighSeries(slider, scope[_this.chartConfig].series)
                          angular.forEach(scope.chart_names, function(chart_cfg_name){
                                scope.$apply(function () {
                                  scope.lowestFlights[chart_cfg_name]  = angular.copy(scope.filterLowestPrice(scope[chart_cfg_name]))
                                  console.log(scope.lowestFlights[chart_cfg_name])
                                });
                          }, scope)
                      }
              });
          }
      }
  });
```

## HTML

```
<ui-select.selectpicker{:theme => "select2", "ng-disabled" => "disabled", "ng-model" => "from", :name => "from", :theme => "select2", "ng-change"=>"updateDeparture(from)", :style => "width: 200px;", :required => "" }
  <ui-select-match{ "ng-cloak"=>"", :placeholder => t("from") } {{$select.selected.t_name}}  {{$select.selected.name}}</ui>
</ui>
<ui-select.selectpicker{"ng-disabled" => "disabled", "ng-model" => "to", :name => "to", :theme => "select2", "ng-change"=>"updateArrival(to)", :style => "width: 200px;", :required => ""}
  <ui-select-match.selectpicker{"ng-cloak"=>"", :placeholder => t("to")}  {{$select.selected.t_name}} {{$select.selected.name}}</ui>
  <ui-select-choices{:repeat => "node in arrivals | filter: $select.search" }
    <span ng-bind-html="node.t_name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    <span ng-bind-html="node.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
  </ui>
</ui>
```

## url params were cleared in `$rootScope.Scope#$digest` cycle

[image: inline]

I put a breakpoint inside `$locationChangeSuccess` and found the url params were cleared in `$rootScope.Scope#$digest` cycle

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
        debugger
        console.log('$locationChangeSuccess changed!', new Date());
    });
});
```

## The 2-way binding not working on directive

The 2-way binding not working on directive,
Actually the 2-way binding works on View, but not working on URL params

[image: inline]

DEMO page http://133.130.101.114:3000/en/user/quick_search/index

### controller(register departChartName and show its value with input box)

```
  $scope.departChartName = "yoyoyo"
  urlBinder.bind($scope, "departChartName", "DPNAME")
```

### slider directive

```
app.directive('ionslider',function($timeout){
    return{
        restrict:'AE',
        scope: false,
        link:function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
            $(element).ionRangeSlider({
                    chartName: element.attr("chart-name"),
                    onChange: function(slider) {
                        scope[this.chartName] = slider.from+"~"+slider.to
                        scope.$apply();
                    }

            });
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: i don't know if you can change the url on the fly like this. but you can edit the url and use $location.path(url) to "redirect"  with the new url param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a service to do a two way binding to a URL parameter:

```
angular.module('app').service('urlBinder', ['$location', function($location) {
    this.bind = function(
        scope,         // angular scope
        varName,       // string : name of the variable on the scope to bind to
        urlParamName   // string : name of the url parameter to bind to
        ) {

        // when scope variable changes, update the URL
        var unhookUrlUpdater = scope.$watch(varName, function(newValue) {
            $location.search(urlParamName, newValue);
        });

        // when the URL changes, update the scope variable
        var unhookScopeUpdater = scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
            var value = $location.search()[urlParamName];

            if (!angular.equals(scope[varName], value)) {
                scope[varName] = value;
            }
        });

        // return a function that can be called to remove the bindings
        return function() {
            unhookUrlUpdater();
            unhookScopeUpdater();
        };
    };
}]);
```

You can also do the same thing with getter/setter function instead of `varName` if the things you are binding aren't on the scope:

```
angular.module('app').service('urlBinder', ['$location', function($location) {
    this.bind = function(scope, getter, setter, urlParamName) {
        var unhookUrlUpdater = scope.$watch(getter, function(newValue) {
            $location.search(urlParamName, newValue);
        });

        var unhookScopeUpdater = scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
            var value = $location.search()[urlParamName];

            if (!angular.equals(getter(), value)) {
                setter(value);
            }
        });

        return function() {
            unhookUrlUpdater();
            unhookScopeUpdater();
        };
    };
}]);
```

In your controller:

```
var someVariable;
urlBinder.bind(
    $scope,
    function() { return someVariable; },
    function(value) { someVariable = value; },
    'url-name');
```

Comment: I tried you solution, but how to use it? How include it into my controller but it didn't work :( https://gist.github.com/poc7667/f9997e01020730fa5297648bd9d17b7c

Comment: Yes inject it in yourt controller then call `urlBinder.bind($scope, 'url-name', 'varName');`, and it should bind `$scope.varName` to the url

Comment: I tried your solution, but I found there must be something wrong with my code.

For example, If I choose  `CHIANGMAI` as the departure, it seems working at first. The url will be `http://133.130.101.114:3000/user/quick_search/index#/?departure_name=CHIANGMAI`

However, it will quickly revert to  `http://133.130.101.114:3000/user/quick_search/index#/`

This is the demo site `http://133.130.101.114:3000/user/quick_search/index#/`

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I think `$scope.watch` calls the function you pass it initially, it might overwrite your value if you set it before doing the binding. You could add a check in to ensure that the newValue is different to the oldValue: `scope.$watch(varName, function(newValue, oldValue) { if (!angular.equals(oldValue, newValue)) ... }`

Comment: I put a breakpoint inside `$locationChangeSuccess` and found the url params were cleared in  `$rootScope.Scope#$digest` cycle, any idea? thanks~

Comment: Perhaps you need to turn `reloadOnSearch` off in your route config? It's difficult to know what's happening without seeing the whole code and being able to debug

Comment: Hi, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined`. `urlBinder.bind($scope, "departure_name", "from")
urlBinder.bind($scope, "dest_name", "to")
` it seems the `this` in your provided code is undefined? And I made it work by removing `this`

Comment: sorry I wrote `this.$location` it should just be `$location`, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Hi You've helped me a lot, I am still applying your ans to my application. Once I finish it, I will approve yours answer. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Hi Basically your solution works on FORM but has some issues on the directive, `The 2-way binding not working on directive,
Actually the 2-way binding works on View, but not working on URL params
` I've updated the problem on my question, any idea? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108387/discussion-between-mike-and-newbike).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use  and withing it you load your html...
so now, within your config you can say, something like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', "$locationProvider",
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        /**
         * Redirect Using Code:
         * Internal: $location.path([path]);
         * External: $window.location.href([link]);
         */
        $routeProvider
        .when("/Taraz/:parent", {
                templateUrl: "/App/pages/taraz/index.html",
                controller: "TarazIndexController",
                resolve: {
                    urlId: ["$route",  function ($route) {
                        return Utility.parseUrlId($route.current.params.parent);//Parent HsbCod
                    }]
                }
            })
```

in here i use /taraz/{code} to reach my data. u use //{your data}
to change url to desired...
secondly...
i resolve urlId... it's very similar to services, you pass it to your controller, but note, if you call same page using multiple route you always have to resolve it(empty, or filled).

```
app.controller('TarazIndexController',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$uibModal', 'urlId', 'FinYearService', 'SarfaslService', 'TarazService',
        function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $uibModal, urlId, FinYearService, SarfaslService, TarazService) {
```

you can use location.path() to send data, and change route.
location.path([route])....

................................................................

there is other way which you can use ui-route, which is more complicated and more featured. it's somehow like the ng-view, but since i didn't use it my self, can't guide you about that.

Answer (score 0):

$location has a getter and a setter. If you look at

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

```
url([url]);
This method is getter / setter.

path([path]);
This method is getter / setter.
```

You can also use search or replace

```
this.$location.search(urlParamName, newValue);

replace();
If called, all changes to $location during the current $digest will replace the current history record, instead of adding a new one.
```

`.when('/about/:name',{})`

```
app.controller("aboutCtrl",function($scope,$routeParams,$route,$location){
    $scope.variable = "'From About Controller'";
    $scope.params = $routeParams.name;
    $scope.locationpath = $location.path();
    $scope.absolutelocationurl = $location.absUrl();
    $scope.locationurl = $location.url();    
    $scope.templateurl = $route.current.templateUrl;    
});
```